# setFrame not working for a UITextLabel of UITableView Cell

Tags: uitableview

I am not able to set the frame of a UITextLabel of a UITableViewCell. I created a CGRect and set that as the frame, but that doesn't seem to work. All of the other properties of the UITextLabel set in the code below (color font and text) are rendered as desired.

```
 UITableViewCell *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        if(!c)
        {
            c = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }

NSString *soundName = [[soundNames objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"Name"];
        UIColor *whiteColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [[c textLabel] setTextColor:whiteColor];
        [[c textLabel] setText:soundName];
        [[c textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Gill Sans" size:17]];

        CGRect textLabelFrame = CGRectMake(50, 7, 270, 29);
        [[c textLabel] setFrame:textLabelFrame];

        return c;
```

Any ideas on what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame of the `textLabel` is changed in `layoutSubviews` method every time cell is showing. You can override `layoutSubviews` method and set custom frame there, or just add your own `UILabel` with predefined frame to the cell.